# Can't create Docker network with none matching gateway

Tags: docker, gateway, docker-network, macvlan

I have a bare metal server on Hetzner with IP 5.6.7.8 and 8 additional IPs reserved for me.

> IPs: 1.2.3.144 to 1.2.3.151
>
> subnet: 1.2.3.144/29
>
> netmask: 255.255.255.248
>
> broadcast: 1.2.3.151
>
> gateway: 5.6.7.8

Now I want to create Docker network with type **macvlan**

```
docker network create macvlan --subnet=1.2.3.144/29 --gateway=5.6.7.8 -o parent=enp0s31f6 macvlan1
```

But this command causes an error

> no matching subnet for gateway 5.6.7.8

Note when I set for example IP 1.2.3.150 and gateway 5.6.7.8 on a *virtual machine* on the host, it works correctly! but I can't set this none matching gateway in *Docker network create* command.